# select a range of text from one Word doc using vba and copy to end of another document and RETAIN formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, range

I have a document "mydoc1" which has headers "Take the Exam" and "Ask a Question" and within those headers is the selection of text that I want to copy to end of another document, "mydoc2". However, that selection has particular formatting which I want to retain when I copy and paste into another document. Its working ok EXCEPT the formatting is NOT being preserved when copied.

```
Sub CutSection()
'
' CutSection Macro
'
' Purpose: display the text between (but not including)
' the words "Take the Exam" and "Ask a Question" if they both appear.
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Dim strTheText As String

Documents.Open FileName:="/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc1.docx"

Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Take the Exam") Then
    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, 
    ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Ask a Question") Then
        strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
        MsgBox strTheText
    End If
End If

Documents("/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc2.docx").Activate
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter strTheText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings don't contain any formatting data, only text.

You could have simply copied and pasted the text:

```
Sub CutSection2()
   Dim doc1 As Document, doc2 As Document
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

   Set doc1 = Documents.Open(FileName:="/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc1.docx")
   Set doc2 = Documents("/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc2.docx")

   Set rng1 = doc1.Range
   If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Take the Exam") Then
      Set rng2 = doc1.Range(rng1.End, doc1.Range.End)
      If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Ask a Question") Then
         doc1.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Copy
         doc2.Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Or, the best option, you could use the `FormattedText` property to transfer the text without using the clipboard.

```
Sub CutSection3()
   Dim doc1 As Document, doc2 As Document
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

   Set doc1 = Documents.Open(FileName:="/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc1.docx")
   Set doc2 = Documents("/Users/xxx/Desktop/mydoc2.docx")

   Set rng1 = doc1.Range
   If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Take the Exam") Then
      Set rng2 = doc1.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
      If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Ask a Question") Then
         doc2.Characters.Last.FormattedText = doc1.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).FormattedText
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have many such documents so simply cutting and pasting was not an option. Yes, I figured the string/text was not right and your best option works great. Thank you.